# how to fix mssql:Error 2 in vs code mssql extension?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

When I have tried to connect to localhost and it was displayed the message about

> "mssql:Error 2: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server.The server was not found
>   or was not accessible.Verify that the instance name is correct and
>   that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections.(provider:Named Pipes Provider,error 40-Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)".

How can I fix it?

I have tried to follow the solution technique given by "[Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)" but i can't find the location of vscode mssql extension configuration tool and SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: Do you know how to find mssql vscode extension SQL Server Instance Name?

Answer (score 1):

You may be changed your computer name. if you changed your computer name then back to set initial name of computer. Then restart your Sql Server(MSSQLSERVER)service.

Comment: E.G. : in SQL Server <version> Configuration Manager choose SQL Server Services and try to find line with name "SQL Server" and check name of server in parentheses (for me: SQLEXPRESS). Next, in window "Connect to Server" in "Server name" click on arrow and find name like: <USER_NAME>\<SQL_SERVER_NAME>.
Also SQL Server should running.